# Why my loop for getting the object property value not working?

Tags: javascript, loops

I am working on a searching program where the users can types the name in prompt box and if it matches with the property name in the `object` property then it displays only that property value. But even when i type the name correctly as in the object it is not displaying the value.

```
var students = [
{
    name: "secil inam",
    track: "front-end web development",
    achievements: 8,
    points: 501
} //an example object i actually have 5 of these
]


var msg = '<div id="home"><ol>';

while(true){ // this loop displays the prompt
var search = prompt("search for a student  name, type quit to exit.");


if( search.toLowerCase() === "quit" || search === null){ // doesn't break if it's null
    break;
}
else
{    
    for(var i = 0; i < students.length; i++){

        if(students[i].name === search){

            for(var key in students[i]){ //this doesn't seem to work
                    msg += '<li>' + key + ': ' + students[i][key] + '</li>';
            }
             break;   
        }
         console.log(i); //this runs
    }
 }

}

msg += '</ol></div>';

document.write(msg);
```

Please advise.

Comment: This looks less like a question, and more like "please debug my code for me". Edit your question so that what you are asking for is clear.

Comment: Where are you trying to display the object? It is entering the for, you just don't do anything with it.

Comment: "loops in loops" work very well in javascript. "doesn't seem to work" - how did you determine that?

Comment: @Kriggs updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `toLowerCase()` on a null object will cause an error, you should switch the order of your conditions in the while loop.

```
if(search === null || search.toLowerCase() === "quit"){
    break;
}
```

After making those changes, it seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/3pjm7sfc/1/

Comment: there is a `break` for `"quit"` entered at the `prompt`

Comment: but sir i dont want it to end when it finds the object and i don't see anything printed in the results page in fiddle.

Comment: You don't have to end when it finds a person. JsFiddle doesn't allow `document.write()`, look at the console output.